# Got an error when I add "changeDetectionStrategy" to my app

Tags: angular, warnings, angular2-changedetection

I'm building my first CRUD,Spring/hib with Angular7 in the frontend. When I try to add the changeDetectionStrategy in my component.ts i get this warnings:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/core.js
10:24-31 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/selector.js
10:24-31 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/ml_parser/html_tags.js
10:24-31 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/ml_parser/tags.js
10:24-31 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted.
```

The app has other components that work just fine and they have the changeDetectionStrategy import. When I add the method to my component angular gives me these errors. I commented all the component,except for @Component stuff and the "export class XY {   }. The error persist till I remove the changeDetectionStrategy. Any Idea of what could it be?

Comment: Show us the bit of code please, with the import

Comment: could you please add your code?

Answer (score 3):

I think that its due to wrong import of changeDetectionStrategey

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
```

replace it by the right one

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
```